# Create an array with three different columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like this in Bigquery:

```
[
  {
"customer_id": "153202836",
"phone_1": "19241293624",
"phone_2": "924 1293624",
"phone_3": "9241293624",
"phone_4": null
  },
  {
"customer_id": "118489602",
"phone_1": "7121159753",
"phone_2": "527122117003",
"phone_3": "2117003",
"phone_4": null
  }
]
```

I am pretty new with Bigquery and I have never used Arrays before. I would like to create one in order to have two columns and two rows:
Column 1: Customer_id (STRING)
Column 2: Phone numbers (ARRAY with all phone numbers excluding NULL values)

In this case, I imagine something like this:

```
customer_id            phones
15320836             ["19243624", "92429624", "9293624"] 
11849602             ["71211753", "5222117003", "2117003"]
```

There is anyway to create this array? Would you reccommend to have information in this format? Would it be harder to get the phones? Should I use STRUCT instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select customer_id, 
  array(
    select split(el, ':')[offset(1)]
    from unnest(arr) el
    where split(el, ':')[offset(1)] != 'null'
  ) phones
from data t, 
unnest([struct(split(translate(to_json_string((select as struct * except(customer_id) from unnest([t]))),'{}"','')) as arr)])
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Assuming **all phone_N columns are of the same STRING data type**  - you can also use below option

```
select customer_id, array_agg(phone) phones 
from data
unpivot (phone for col in (phone_1, phone_2, phone_3, phone_4))
group by customer_id
```

with same output as above

Note: this option already presented in Samuel's answer  - but it was a little overengineered, so I added better one to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_id, [phone_1,phone_2,phone_3 ] as phone_array
from (
SELECT
  "153202836" AS customer_id,
  "19241293624" phone_1,
  "924 1293624" phone_2,
  "9241293624" AS phone_3,
  NULL AS phone_4
UNION ALL
SELECT
  "118489602",
  "7121159753",
  "527122117003",
  "2117003",
  NULL
)
```

or as `unpivot` for empty phone numbers:

```
select customer_id, array_agg(phones order by phone_row) as phones_array
from(
Select * except (phone_1, phone_2, phone_3 ,phone_4), 
    cast(phone_1 as string) phone_1, cast(phone_2 as string) phone_2,
    cast(phone_3 as string) phone_3, cast(phone_4 as string) phone_4
from (
SELECT
  "153202836" AS customer_id,
  "19241293624" phone_1,
  "924 1293624" phone_2,
  "9241293624" AS phone_3,
  NULL AS phone_4
UNION ALL
SELECT
  "118489602",
  "7121159753",
  "527122117003",
  "2117003",
  NULL
)
)
UNPIVOT(phones FOR phone_row IN (phone_1,phone_2,phone_3, phone_4 ))
group by customer_id
```